# HttpWebResponse with Multiple Parts

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebresponse

We have a server at work that we can query for photos using a web service. The person that maintains the server is a Java developer but I need to be able to query the server using dotNET as I'm using an SDK to integrate with an existing application we are running, and she is reluctant/unable to assist with dotNET.

This is my request for the photo (note the required certificate):-

```
private WebResponse Request()
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Validate);
    X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("wmbuat.crt");

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server.Text);
    request.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

    GetXml().Save(request.GetRequestStream());
    return request.GetResponse();
}

private static Boolean Validate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return true;
}
```

I can query the server no dramas, but the HttpWebResponse contains two parts in the one stream - an XML part containing information about the photo, and a binary part that is a JPEG. For example:-

```
--WMBMIME2Boundaryurn_uuid_C123
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:C123@ibm.com>

<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">...</NS1:Envelope>
--WMBMIME2Boundaryurn_uuid_C123
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <987>

yoya..JFIF...
```

I've seen a couple of questions on here relating to this, but I don't seem to be able to use a certificate with these libraries. Is there simply a way to wrap the output stream to get the parts as separate objects? I'm happy for it to just be String and byte[], and I can convert it to XML and Image myself.

I tried using a StreamReader and reading up to the second blank line, which is where the binary data starts, then reading the remainder from the original Stream to a file, but that did not work :-/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that is trying to accomplish something similar, I've done a bit of a workaround for the purpose of this proof of concept. It's not the most efficient code, but it gets the job done in the short term while I work on improving it in-between everything else I have to get done :-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace COPS_Photo_Viewer
{
    public partial class CPV : Form
    {
        public CPV()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textIP.Text = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[0].MapToIPv4().ToString();
            textID.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            textMachine.Text = Dns.GetHostName();
            textApplication.Text = Application.ProductName;
        }

        private Image ExtractImage(byte[] binary)
        {
            int start = 0;
            for (; start < binary.Length; ++start)
                if (((char)binary[start]) == 'ÿ')
                    break;

            byte[] image = new byte[binary.Length - start];
            for (int index = start; index < binary.Length; ++index)
                image[index - start] = binary[index];

            return Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(image));
        }

        private void GetImage(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            WebResponse response = Request();
            byte[] input = ReadStream(response.GetResponseStream());
            photograph.Image = ExtractImage(input);
        }

        private XmlDocument GetXml()
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(...);
            return xml;
        }

        private byte[] ReadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            Queue<byte> input = new Queue<byte>();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

            for (int read = stream.ReadByte(); read >= 0; read = stream.ReadByte())
                input.Enqueue((byte)read);

            return input.ToArray<byte>();
        }

        private WebResponse Request()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Validate);
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate =
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("wmbuat.crt");

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textURL.Text);
            request.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Accept = "text/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            GetXml().Save(request.GetRequestStream());
            return request.GetResponse();
        }

        private static Boolean Validate(Object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

GetImage is initially run when a button on the form is pressed. Once there is a result, it turns the response stream into a byte array, then searches for the first instance of "ÿ" (which is only ever going to appear at the start of the JPEG in our situation), then turns the remainder of the array into a MemoryStream which is then turned into an image.

Obviously reading one byte at a time into a Queue isn't the best, but fortunately this is being run across a network so (at least during this initial development phase) it's not an issue and the photo still loads instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The client, request and response classes you are using are from the `System.Net` namespace, which abstracts a little less for you than some of the newer classes from the `System.Net.Http` namespace. Like anything new, there's less documentation and examples, but in this particular case I think using the client classes shipped with the "Microsoft WebAPI Framework" will benefit you.

Specifically, the response class in the WebAPI framework is called `HttpResponseMessage`, and it has a property

```
HttpResponseMessage response = ...
HttpContent content = response.Content;
if(content is MultipartContent)
{
    // loop through parts
}
```

You can find more documentation on this different namespace here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

One deal-breaker may be being on an older version of .NET. I believe WebAPI 2 requires the latest and greatest version, 4.5, but you may find one for version 4. I haven't worked with the prior version, but I imagine that the parsing they do to separate it into multiple content parts is non-trivial.

Comment: Hi welegan,
Thanks for that, but yeah, as your mentioned, I only have access to dotNET 4.0 (technically most of the PC's in our workplace are running 3.5 but I can upgrade any of them to 4.0 as needed). We're still on XP so I can't install 4.5.

Comment: yikes, ok good luck then with finding a good way to parse out http mime parts, I'm sure there are tutorials for that but there's a lot of gotchas iirc.